# Android remove focus of TextEdit when Enter is pressed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, focus, material-components-android

I have some `TextEdit` inside a `LinearLayout` and I want to remove the cursor after I hit enter on them.

#### Code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".activity.SettingActivity"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtInterval1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Edit Text 1"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtInterval1"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:autofillHints="no"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtInterval2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Edit Text 2"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtInterval2"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:autofillHints="no"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="3"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtInterval3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Edit Text 3"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtInterval3"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:autofillHints="no"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="3"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

</LinearLayout>
```

#### Problem

After some time pressing enter on the keyboard, the marker (circled in red) disappears but the cursor is still there.

[image]

Also as it might change I'm using Material3 as a theme:

```xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar">
        ...
    </style>
</resources>
```

How can I remove the cursor and any other hint (after enter is pressed). I feel this makes the user think they are still editing that field and that focus should be lost after pressing enter. I'm thinking of using `setOnKeyListener` and loose focus there, but I wanted to know the proper solution to this as it seems a pretty common scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` doesn't work, you can call `setOnEditorActionListener()` on the EditText view:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {        
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int act, KeyEvent event) {
        if(act == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
             editText.clearFocus();
        }
    return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Yep, I currently have `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` on the `EditText` (as shown in the above snippet) but I doesn't work the way I intended to. Basically in `setOnKeyListener` I need to call `clearFocus()` on the `EditText`?

Comment: Actually, you can just use  setOnEditorActionListener() on the EditText view. I'm udpating my answer

Comment: Just tried it and it behaves as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add one more thing to the answer after clear focus hideSoftInputFromWindow Manager

```
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {        
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int act, KeyEvent event) {
        if(act == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
             editText.clearFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more, why is this needed?